# How to iterate a blocking iterator with asyncio?

Tags: python, iterator, python-asyncio

A 3rd-party API library provides an iterator for listing items and features built-in pagination. It's blocking and I would like to do multiple listing in parallel.

```
async def list_multiple(params_list):
    async_tasks = []
    for params in params_list:
        async_tasks.append(list_one(**params))
    await asyncio.gather(*async_tasks)


async def list_one(**kwargs):
    blocking_iterator = some_library.get_api_list_iterator(**kwargs)
    async for item in iterate_blocking(blocking_iterator):
        pass  # do things


async def iterate_blocking(iterator):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    while True:
        try:
            yield await loop.run_in_executor(None, iterator.next)
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

But doing this raises

```
TypeError: StopIteration interacts badly with generators and cannot be raised into a Future
```

and blocks all threads. How do I iterate a blocking iterator correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the method used for iteration is called `__next__` in Python 3, not `next`. `next` works probably because of some Python 2 compatibility code being set up by the library.

You can fix the issue by catching `StopIteration` while still in the auxilliary thread, and using a different exception, or another kind of signal, to indicate end of iteration. For example, this code uses a sentinel object:

```
async def iterate_blocking(iterator):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    DONE = object()
    def get_next():
        try:
            return iterator.__next__()
        except StopIteration:
            return DONE

    while True:
        obj = await loop.run_in_executor(None, get_next)
        if obj is DONE:
            break
        yield obj
```

This can be further simplified using the two-argument form of the `next` built-in, which does essentially the same thing as `get_next`:

```
async def iterate_blocking(iterator):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    DONE = object()
    while True:
        obj = await loop.run_in_executor(None, next, iterator, DONE)
        if obj is DONE:
            break
        yield obj
```

(Both above examples are untested, so typos are possible.)

Comment: Ah, I was hoping there is a better way. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Andrei Better in the sense of avoiding the use of a sentinel, or better in the sense of avoiding `run_in_executor` altogether? Also, are you worrtied about efficiency or about the number of lines? The second snippet is failrly minimalistic in terms of LOC.

Comment: Just expected there was a way without an extra function and an object instance, but oh well, gotta limit my appetite for minimalistic code.

Comment: @Andrei The second snippet avoids the extra function by making use of the functionality of `next`. Object instance can be made global if you don't care about reentrance, but I find it safer to just create it every time (and `object()` is as efficient as it gets).

Comment: Since the iterator would never normally return StopIteration class, I am thinking to use it instead of object instance. A bit more fine to my taste :)

Comment: @Andrei You can do as you wish, but that makes the code brittle, as you can't reuse it for other situations where returning the `StopIteration` object might be possible. The worst aspect of such design is that if the code ever does it, it would just silently fail without any indication of error.